# Is there a limit on WebSocket retrys?

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling, websocket

I'm coding up a snippet of JavaScript to talk to a custom C# web-socket server, and as per, I'm following recommended practice to retry the connection.

The server, may not be ready when the JS is ready, so what I need to do is to keep trying to connect to the websocket until it eventually succeeds.

Recommended practice, tells me that I either need to trap the onclose event or the onerror event, and in either of those, attempt to re-connect, preferably with some kind of back-off strategy.

Based on this advice, I've came up with the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>WS</h1>

        <button onclick="init()">Connect</button>
        <button onclick="deInit()">Disconnect</button>
        <button onclick="send()">Message</button>

        <script>

            var mySocket;

            function init(){

                mySocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000/foolish");

                mySocket.onopen = function(){
                    console.log("OPEN");
                };

                mySocket.onclose = function(status){
                    console.log("CLOSE");
                    console.log(status);
                    if(status.code === 1006){
                        mySocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000/foolish");
                    }
                };

                mySocket.onerror = function(err){
                    console.log("ERROR");
                    console.log(err);
                };

                mySocket.onmessage = function(msg){
                    console.log("MESSAGE");
                    console.log(msg);
                };

            }

            function deInit(){

                mySocket.close();

            }

            function send(){

                mySocket.Send("foo");

            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Iv'e tried performing the re-connect in the error handler, and attaching to a "setTimeOut" call, too and the output is always the same.

My event handlers, trigger once, re-attempting a connection, but the second time it fails, none of the event handlers get triggered, and I'm left just looking at a failed attempt, as the following image shows:

[image]

Everything I've read tells me that every time I retry, and fail to connect, my error handler and/or close handler should continue to fire allowing me the option to handle the error, but it does not it tries twice and gives up.

This happens in IE11, IE10, Chrome 50+ and FireFox latest version.

Given how consistent it is across browsers, then I'mm guessing that it's either by design or it's something I'm doing wrong, however I'm really not seeing what the issue is.

If Anyone has any ideas, i'd be much appreciated if you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the new instance on close you dont re-apply the event handlers

Comment: Of course.  How the hell did I manage to miss that one :-) well spotted.  Always something simple ain't it.